# value is not added to multidimensional array

Tags: javascript

The first time the function fires I get this result:

```
output1:test
```

The output2 2 alert is not firing. I know something is probably undefined in alert Does anyone know why the value won't be added in the multidimensional array?

I expect this to display after the false1:

```
output2:test2
```

Also if you want to fiddle with the code here it is: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ndf0sjgf/1/

```js
var carSelectedArray = [
  [null]
];

addRow(carSelectedArray);
addRow(carSelectedArray);

function addRow(carSelectedArray) {
  var arrayempty = false;
  if (carSelectedArray[0][0] == null || carSelectedArray.length == 0) {
    arrayempty = true;

  } else {
    arrayempty = false;
  }


  if (arrayempty == true) {
    carSelectedArray[0][0] = "test";
    alert("output1:" + carSelectedArray[0][0]);

  } else {

    carSelectedArray[1][0] = "test2";
    alert("output2:" + carSelectedArray[1][0]);

  }
}
```

Comment: One question.. Where is JQuery ?

Comment: I created a snippet for you as you could have done clicking the `<>`  - it immediately shows the error you have - you only have ONE nested array.

Comment: Jeah but how do i fix this?  I can't seem to push into the array.

Comment: `carSelectedArray[1] = carSelectedArray[1] || [];    carSelectedArray[1][0] = "test2";
    alert("output2:" + carSelectedArray[1][0]);` or define the initial array with two arrays: `var carSelectedArray = [[null],[null]];`

Comment: Oh my god it works. But why?

Comment: Because you need to define both arrays in the array. My code just tests to see if there IS a [1] - if not, create it.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop works well, however your didn't define your array well.

there is only 1 dimension here :

```
var carSelectedArray = [[null]];
```

So replace with this :

```
var carSelectedArray = [[],[]];
```

PS : `null` is not required

and at the beginning in your function, you define arrayempty to false, so you can remove this :

```
else {
    arrayempty = false;
  }
```

Solution here : https://plnkr.co/edit/Qikalr0jc54R3MRSea4G?p=preview

```js
var carSelectedArray = [[],[]];

addRow(carSelectedArray);
addRow(carSelectedArray);

function addRow(carSelectedArray) {
  var arrayempty = false;
  if (carSelectedArray[0][0] == null || carSelectedArray.length == 0) {
    arrayempty = true;
  }


  if (arrayempty == true) {
    carSelectedArray[0][0] = "test";
    alert("output1:" + carSelectedArray[0][0]);

  } else {
    carSelectedArray[1][0] = "test2";
    alert("output2:" + carSelectedArray[1][0]);

  }
}
```

Comment: The question was already answered in the comment. You do have enough rep to vote to close as "typo-type" question

Comment: 1 minute later ;)

Comment: so after thinking about the problem, find a solution and post it. If someone comments after me, I have to delete my answer? Logic;)

Comment: maybe cause it's your comment ?

Comment: No need to delete, Just a suggestion to vote to close since it is really not worth answering. I am sure there is even a duplicate but I was too lazy to find it